# Get Mac dock size in tkinter

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

Is it possible to get the size of the macOS dock using Python/tkinter? Specifically I need the width of a side-placed dock, to limit a tk window width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use private C API (as in link below)
https://github.com/asmagill/hammerspoon_asm.undocumented/blob/master/coredock/coredock.h

Or

you can read dock settings and calculate it from /users//Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist